# HTML heading link doesn't work, JavaScript set to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript and my first project is a portfolio website. My header scrolls to different locations on the page. I am trying to also include a link to LinkedIn and Instagram, but that throws the following error when trying to open it:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.instagram.com/
at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
at n (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scripts.min.js:12)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Code:

```js
    // Animate to section when nav is clicked
    $('header a').click(function(e) {

        // Treat as normal link if no-scroll class
        if ($(this).hasClass('no-scroll')) return;

        e.preventDefault();
        var heading = $(this).attr('href');
        var scrollDistance = $(heading).offset().top;

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollDistance + 'px'
        }, Math.abs(window.pageYOffset - $(heading).offset().top) / 1);

        // Hide the menu once clicked if mobile
        if ($('header').hasClass('active')) {
            $('header, body').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

```css
@keyframes dropHeader {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    animation-name: dropHeader;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 0.75s
}

header ul {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}

header li {
    display: inline-block
}

header a {
    display: block;
    color: #4f7942;
    padding: 10px
}

header a:hover {
    color: #476A34;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px
}

header a:focus {
    color: #4f7942;
    text-decoration: none
}

header.active {
    display: block
}

header.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999
}

#menu.active {
    display: block
}

#mobile-menu-open {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    color: #4f7942;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 20;
    padding: 0 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff
}

#mobile-menu-close {
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #4f7942
}

#mobile-menu-close span {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

#mobile-menu-close i {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div id="mobile-menu-close">
            <span>Close</span> <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="shadow" id="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#education">Education</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#masters">Master's Research</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#experience">Experience</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">Photography</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">LinkedIn</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

Do you have any suggestions about how to get the link to work? I think it is an issue with my JavaScript not knowing how to handle the link, but I do not know how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS has a way to handle this:

```js
// Treat as normal link if no-scroll class
if ($(this).hasClass('no-scroll')) return;
```

So if you put the class `no-scroll` in your Instagram and LinkedIn links, the JS will not try to take over the click.

```html
<a class="no-scroll" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">LinkedIn</a>
```